# Problems deleting a row with php

Tags: php, mysql

I'm trying to remove a row from a table with php. I have the following piece of code:

```
<?php
   if($_GET["act"] == 'eliminarart' && $_GET["id"] != '')
   {
       var_dump($_GET);
       if($mysql->query("DELETE FROM landing_articulos WHERE id_articulo = ". intval($_GET["id"])." LIMIT 1")){
           redirige('nuevapagina.php');
       } else {
           $e=$mysqli->error;
           echo $e;
       }
   }
?>

<head>
    <script language="javascript">
        function eliminar_art(id){
            var mensaje = 'Deseas eliminar este articulo?';
            eliminar = confirm(mensaje);
            if (eliminar)
                document.location='nuevapagina.php?act=eliminarart&id='+id;
        }
    </script>
</head>
```

I call all this code here:

```
while($f1 = mysql_fetch_array($c1)){
    ?>
    <div style="float:left; width:32%; padding-left:0px; color:#ef5000; font-weight:bold; margin:5px;"><p><a href="http://www.certifacil.es/articulos/<?=$f1["url"]?>" target="_blank"><strong><?=$f1["nombre"];?></strong></a> <a href="editar_nuevapagina.php?id=<?=$f1["id_articulo"]?>"><img src="imagenes/lapiz.png" width="15" height="15" border="0"/></a> </a> <a href="javascript:eliminar_art('<?=$f1["id_articulo"]?>');"><img src="imagenes/delete.png" width="15" height="15" border="0"/></a> <? if($f1["valido"]=='0')echo ' - SIN VALIDAR';?></p></div><?
}
```

The `var_dump` returns data, although the id I get is a string instead of an int as it's defined in the database. So what I am doing wrong? All this code is in a page called `nuevapagina.php`.

Comment: Why do you have `mysql_fetch_array()` when you are using MySQLi?

Comment: Please post the output from the `var_dump()`. By "a string", do you mean that it is a numeric string (`$_GET` is always strings), or a non-numeric character string? In the latter case, it would cast to zero with `intval()` and possibly not match any rows.

Comment: So what exactly is not working?

Comment: @luweiqi That is probably a variable containing a mysqli object, that just happens to be named `$mysql`.

Comment: @MichaelBerkowski True, didn't catch that

Comment: Use [Prepared Statements](http://php.net/manual/en/pdo.prepared-statements.php) for your data checking value inserts.

Comment: There is **no more support** for `mysql_*` functions, they are [**officially deprecated**](https://wiki.php.net/rfc/mysql_deprecation), **no longer maintained** and will be [**removed**](http://php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-connect.php#warning) in the future. You should update your code with [PDO](http://php.net/pdo) or [MySQLi](http://php.net/msqli) to ensure the functionality of your project in the future. Note you're also vulnerable to SQL injection.

Comment: @Bono they have already been removed as of PHP7

Comment: @Martin I need to update my comments ;) Thanks for the heads-up

Comment: Oh I didn't read far enough down - you are apparently mixing the mysqli API with the older `mysql_*()` functions - they are not compatible or interchangeable.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

no need to convert into integer just simply do it as:

```
$mysql->query("DELETE FROM landing_articulos WHERE id_articulo = ".$_GET["id"]." LIMIT 1"
```

Comment: @Qirel if OP had any concern for security they would be using Prepared Statements.

Comment: He isn't using prepared statements but he is filtering the input variable with `intval`